# Web App not requesting LOCATION permission on mobile website

Tags: reactjs, permissions, geolocation, mobile-website

i am building a very simple app that requires the geo-location of visitors. I use the react navigator geoLocator for this. My desired behavior is to show the gps coordinates when permission has been granted and show a custom "needs location" screen when location permission is not granted or is revoked. It works perfectly on the desktop, but when I visit the website on mobile, the location permission is never requested.

Here is my custom hook that gets location:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useGeoLocation = () => {
    const [location, setLocation] = useState({
        loaded: false,
        coordinates: { lat: "", lng: "" },
    });

    const onSuccess = (location) => {
        setLocation({
            loaded: true,
            coordinates: {
                lat: location.coords.latitude,
                lng: location.coords.longitude,
            },
        });
    };

    const onError = (error) => {
        setLocation({
            loaded: true,
            error: {
                code: error.code,
                message: error.message,
            },
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        // if the browser does not support geo-location (unlikely)
        if (!("geolocation" in navigator)) {
            onError({
                code: 0,
                message: "Geolocation not supported",
            });
        }

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
    }, []);

    return location;
};

export default useGeoLocation;
```

And then here is my App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import useGeoLocation from './custom_hooks/useGeolocation';
import CircularProgress from '@mui/material/CircularProgress';
import NoLocation from './components/NoLocation'

function App() {

  const location = useGeoLocation();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {location.loaded ? <div>{location.coordinates ? JSON.stringify(location.coordinates) : <NoLocation />}</div> : <CircularProgress style={{color: '#d500f9'}} />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am not entirely sure why it does not work appropriately when I visit the website from mobile

**QUESTION: What is the right way to test on mobile so I can retrieve location without having to deploy the app?**

Comment: When I switch to the mobile viewport, it works for me in the browser. When you mentioned visiting the site from mobile, do you mean an actual mobile device with debugging enabled? In that case, could your location be disabled on the mobile device ?

Comment: @novice yes i mean an actual mobile device, using google chrome or safari. The site is running on my localhost, so I visit the localhost IP using my phone but the location permission is never requested

Comment: have same issue in 2024 . have you solve the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I tested your [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-agnesi-tgox5e?file=/src/App.js) on Chrome on Desktop, Brave on Android and Safari on iPhone and it worked totally fine - I saw the permission pop up correctly. But, only if the location services on the device were enabled **beforehand**.

You can see [this](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/1339#issuecomment-360942159) reference as well.

Comment: May I ask how you're running the app? Maybe it's because of how i'm running it

Comment: codesandbox builds the code and you can see it creates a page for that purpose, like https://tgox5e.csb.app. you can access it via the desktop and also iphone/android and see what happens if you have GPS on/off.

Comment: You're right. Then it seems it must be with some configuration in which I'm running my app

Answer (score 0):

What I have observed is that chrome mobile browser is not allowing to enable location on sites not having HTTPS layer as it exposes sensitive information to attackers.
So in case of localhost it runs on http so it is not allowing the location to be enabled. But codesandbox has https layer so it is allowing the site to request for the location.
I don't know whether my answer is correct or not and please correct me if I'm wrong :)